# Seaborn automatically scaling Y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using Seaborn to plot some data.

The problem I am facing is that Y-axis is automatically getting scaled and not showing actual numbers.

```
survive_count = sns.barplot(x="Pclass", y='Survived', data=df)
```

[image]

What can be the possible solution to eliminate this?

After few suggestions, I tried

```
survive_count = sns.countplot(x="Pclass", hue='Survived', data=df)
survive_count.figure.savefig(my_path + '/Class vs Survival Count.png')
```

But, unfortunately, I landed up on another problem

[image]

I am really confused why I am having this inverted image.

To solve this, I tried

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

and

```
plt.ylim(reversed(plt.ylim()))
```

But both solutions did not work.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: It is tough to say at this point. As I am still facing an abnormal behaviour by the Seaborn library. I'll update the things I did and the result I am getting

Comment: Is this question still open? Or is it answered now?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a countplot. By default, a barplot averages out the values.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
ax = sns.countplot(x="pclass", data=df[df['survived'] == 1])
plt.show()
```

[image: example of a countplot]

Or using `hue`:

```py
sns.set_theme("paper")
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
ax = sns.countplot(x="pclass", hue="survived", data=df)
```

[image: countplot with hue]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your suggestion helped me partially. Unfortunately, I am now facing another funny problem. By using sns.countplot, I am getting inverted y-axis without scale. I used plt.ylim(reversed(plt.ylim())) to invert the yaxis but still no help with markers.

Comment: Both problems are very unusual, they certainly aren't the default behavior. It's hard to know what you're doing wrong without seeing the code. Can you edit the question's post and add code for a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

the reason I guess is that seaborns bar plot do the mean value of the category.
Please see if any of the code below helps you.

```
survive_count = sns.barplot(x="Pclass", y='Survived', data=df, estimator=sum)
```

```
survive_count = sns.barplot(x="Pclass", y='Survived', data=df, estimator=len)
```

```
from numpy import count_nonzero
survive_count = sns.barplot(x="Pclass", y='Survived', data=df, estimator= count_nonzero)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @aj7amigo, both estimator options with sum and len works. Though the meaning is different for both. We might use any one of them depending upon our requirement. count_nonzero does not work and throws back a syntax error.

Comment: @RajRajeshwariPrasad - for the 3rd option you need to import the following.

`from numpy import count_nonzero`

It should work then I hope. You are right, which option to choose depends totally on the use case.